# Query not loading get_post_meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post, meta

The function below is used to load my custom post type posts.  The problem is that it isn't loading the get_post_meta data.  I have this in my functions.php file.  Do I need something added to the get_post_meta since it's in the functions file?

```
function get_latest_post(){ 
global $wpdb; 

$num=$_POST['numposts'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = split('page',$id);
$id = str_replace('/','',$id[1]);
if($id!=0)
{
$offst = $id*$num-$num;
}else $offst=0;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();  $wp_query->query('post_type=video_posts&orderby=date&posts_per_page='.$num.'&offset='.$offst); 
if($wp_query->have_posts()) : $i = 1; while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
<?php $embeds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rm_video_embed_code');  ?>
<?php $thumbnail_id = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
preg_match ('/src="(.*)" class/',$thumbnail_id,$link);  
if(!empty($thumbnail_id)) {
$image_path =  thumbGen($link[1],190,0,"crop=1&halign=center&valign=center&return=1");
$image_all = get_bloginfo('url').$image_path;
$my_image = array_values(getimagesize($image_all));
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $my_image;
}
?>
<div class="pop_<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;"><div class="bClose"></div>
<?php foreach($embeds as $embed) { echo $embed; }?>
</div>

<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="video_popup_<?php echo $i; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<div class="video_title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="video_description"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<div><img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</a></li>    
<?php endif; ?>   
<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; //wp_reset_query();     
if((1==1)===FALSE){ 
echo "Oops! System error!"; 
}
else { 
}
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_latest_post', 'get_latest_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_latest_post', 'get_latest_post');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't loading the qet_post_meta data".  What happens?  Does `$embeds` end up with a different value then expected?  Does the script cease to run?  Are you getting errors?  What specifically happens?

Comment: No data is loaded.  It returns nothing.  If I echo it, nothing is shown.

Comment: What happens is you `var_dump()` it?  You really should not use `echo` for debugging purposes.  You might need to look into that function itself to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: it returns:  bool(false)

Comment: OK, well look at the function and see what conditions would make it return `false`. If you debug back through the code, you will probably be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: AH got it! - needed `global $post;`

Comment: Glad to see you got it worked out.  Go ahead and provide an answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the function `global $post;`